# Django 1.10.6 Limiting Querysets to return lastly entered records?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

Refer - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

I searched SO dont find the required info. Need to retrieve only 5 lastly entered records , within a Querset..

Documentation linked here - Refer - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets
 shows how to retrieve the earliest entered records .

Comment: Always add your code alongwith the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use descending order and set limit for it.

```
YourModel.objects.all().order_by('-YouColumn')[5:]
```

Comment: Thanks Zulfugar - the below code worked slightly  better for me  - `YourModel.objects.all().order_by('-YouColumn')[0:5]`## Gets the Last 5 Records inserted in DB along with order_by

Comment: i have upvoted but dont have enough reputation yet - thanks again !!